Advice on Moving Object Segmentation with U-Net where the target is small
I have a problem I'm trying to solve. I'd like to spot a moving object in a video sequence. "Moving Object" is very vague, but it can be roughly defined as 'here is a bright point that seems consistent and moves from frame to frame".
So far, I've built a U-Net that attempts to segment a 3D volume. The volume is X and Y in space, and Z for time. A consistent moving object would appear as a diagonal line through that volume (or at least, not a line parallel to the Z axis).
The U-Net is fairly standard - I've converted it to use 3D Convolutional layers, and ConvTranspose3D o on the Decoder side. I concatenate across layers as normal for a U-Net. I'm predicting only one class, so the output is a bunch of logits with the shape (Batch Size, 1, t y, x).
Here is an example video of the input data:
https://youtu.be/LqVMp0B5Vg8
Bottom right, you can see the target. I've put a box around it.
My model produces this:
https://youtu.be/RrQYmub4yNs
Looks pretty good right? Indeed it is, but there are problems. There's an initial flash at the beginning which we don't want, but even worse, we get lots of 'tiny flashes' over a long period. Sometimes, we get the following problem. Here is a flattened input mask that I want the network to learn:

But this is what we get:

It's definitely picked up the track, but it's also got a lot of the cruft from the background. Some of that might indeed be movement, but the majority of the extra crud is, well, crud.
These images are in the 'raw format' i.e rectangular and not polar transformed like the videos. I've flattened them down to 2D for visualisation purposes, but these white spots are on one of sixteen frames. I've squashed them down so we can see the extent of the track.
My theory - the network is learning background removal and not the moving object. This is a problem for me going forward as I need the network to be more general. I realise this is 'the game I'm playing' and the goal of many a system.
I'm using two losses here - the nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() from pytorch, and a dice_loss function:
def dice_loss(input: Tensor, target: Tensor):
    """ Dice loss (objective to minimize) between 0 and 1
    Average of Dice coefficient for the batch. Input tensor is batch, 1, d, h, w. """
    assert input.size() == target.size()
    assert input.dim() == 5
    epsilon = 1e-3 # Could be bigger actually, even 1.0 as a smooth factor

    sum_dim = (2, 3, 4)

    inter = 2 * (input * target).sum(dim=sum_dim)

    sets_sum = input.sum(dim=sum_dim) + target.sum(dim=sum_dim)
    sets_sum = torch.where(sets_sum == 0, inter, sets_sum)

    dice = (inter + epsilon) / (sets_sum + epsilon)
    assert(dice.mean() <= 1.0)
    return 1.0 - dice.mean()

Now this is where things get interesting. I get the following training loss curve:

This curve does not change regardless of learning rate, number of layers in the U-Net or even image size or depth. This shape always occurs. I've managed to find out why. It's the combination of BCE and Dice.
If I just use BCE, the output of the network is a black rectangle - all zeroes. We get a nice, smooth, classic loss curve. If I use the dice loss with BCE, I get much better results, but the loss varies wildly as can be seen in the graph. I think the network learns to remove the background where the BCE loss changes (and dice does not) but once BCE has gone as far as it can go, Dice takes over somehow and we get some good answers, but with the problem of tiny blips.
These blips are a problem, because one defining factor of a moving object is  more than one frame. I'm seeing things appear for a frame which suggests motion hasn't been learned. If we consider the example of an object moving from the top left to the bottom right, that would result in a diagonal line that advances 1 pixel in each dimension - something a 3D convolution could (and should) become sensitive to.
My question is "How can I be sure if the network is just learning background?" and if so, "How can I get it to learn to spot motion?".
I have a few ideas on how to improve this. Maybe breaking up the image into tiles and working on each tile individually, then combining, in order to make the moving object in the field "appear bigger".  I've tried dilating the convolutional kernels but this doesn't appear to change things too much. Perhaps larger kernel sizes might be a good idea? I've shrunk the network down by a layer but performance seemed to suffer a bit.
I wondered if any folks here could spare a little time please; any advice would be great.
